# open outlook mail in customized form

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a small application in Excel-VBA which takes inputs from a user and the application sends and email to me the inputs in an encrypted form.
Now, I have a macro in outlook-vba which takes care of decryption and saves data in required format, so that's not a problem. What I need is I want to open that specific mail from the user in a customized format so that without running that script I could see the data.
E.g. The data comes in like this

```
1~Saurav Gupta~100^2~Sachin Rana~200^
```

Now I want it to be shown as in a tabular format in a form, say

```
S.No Name       Marks 
1   Saurav Gupta  100 
2   Sachin Rana   200
```

Any idea how can I achieve that?

Thanks and regards
Saurav.

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin `Split` function to separate the lines and the fields in the data:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitTest()
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim sLines() As String
    Dim sFields() As String
    Dim iLine As Integer

    sInput = "1~Saurav Gupta~100^2~Sachin Rana~200^"

    '***** Split sInput into lines
    sLines = Split(sInput, "^")

    '***** Do something with the lines
    For iLine = 0 To UBound(sLines) - 1
        Debug.Print sLines(iLine)

        '***** Split each line into fields
        sFields = Split(sLines(iLine), "~")

        '***** Do something with the fields
        Debug.Print "#1. " & sFields(0) & ", #2. " & sFields(1) & ", #3. " & sFields(2)
    Next iLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but is there any way I can build a cutom form in outlook and then show this in that form when I double click that mail in my inbox?

Comment: I guess you should be able to, but I don't know exactly how at the moment. Give it a try and ask another question if you get stuck.